# How to plot Root Locus without using special Matlab functions

Tags: matlab, plot, transfer-function

I need to plot the Root Locus with a changing "k" of a given transfer function without using any special Matlab functions i.e., "rlocus", "tf". I'm allow to use roots. The code bellow displays an error/warning message (Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.) that I have not been able to figure out .

See my code.

```
%In vector form
num = input('Enter the coefficients of numerator of J(s): ');
%In vector form 
den = input('Enter the coefficients of denominator of J(s): ');
qs = 0; 
for k = 0:0.1:1000; 
qs(k,:) = roots(den + num.*k); 
end; 
plot(qs,'+'), xlabel('\sigma'), ylabel('j\omega'), title ('Root-Locus'), grid
```

Thank you

Comment: You are indexing `qs(k,:)` but `q` is not always an integer, you're trying to do `q(0,:)=...`, `q(0.1,:)=...`, etc. The Matlab error message told you exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I need k to go from zero to a large number and if I try to change it to start at 1, I get another error message (Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.)

Answer (score 0):

As @David already described in a comment, the problem is that you are using `k=0:0.1:1000` as index. You are therefore trying to access `qs(0)`, `qs(0.1)`, ..., which is not possible in MATLAB. The index has to be an integer value *larger* than 0, i.e. starting at **1**. (unlike in most programming languages, where indexing starts at **0**).

I would suggest separating `k` and the index variable by creating a vector `k` containing `0:0.1:1000` and then using a separate variable (e.g. `ii`) as index variable in the for loop:

```
%In vector form
num = input('Enter the coefficients of numerator of J(s): ');
%In vector form 
den = input('Enter the coefficients of denominator of J(s): ');
qs = 0; 
k = 0:0.1:1000;
for ii = 1:length(k)
    qs(ii,:) = roots(den + num.*k(ii)); 
end; 
plot(qs,'+'), xlabel('\sigma'), ylabel('j\omega'), title ('Root-Locus'), grid
```